# Is it possible to clip the image for google map Marker

Tags: angular, google-maps-markers, clip, image-clipping

Currently I am using Angular and google map API. I put some of markers on google map and try to change it as custom icons. However, in this case, I would like to put many icons for one image file and use the icons by clipping.

For the CSS, I could use `clip` but I don't know it is possible to clip image for google map's marker. Anybody know it is available? or not?